# JQuery Mobile - POST a form and get response

Tags: post, jquery-mobile

Greetings,

I have the following jquery mobile page:

```
<div data-role="content">
    <center>
    <img src="./images/logo320.png" />
    </center>

    <br><br>

    <form method="POST" action="./ajax/login.php">
      <label for="login_unameLabel">Username:</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="login_uname" id="login_uname" /><br>

      <label for="login_pwordLabel">Password:</label><br>  
      <input type="password" name="login_pword" id="login_pword" /><br>

      <button id="login_submit" type="submit" data-theme="a">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

./ajax/login.php returns either "OK" or "NOK". How can I capture this result in my page?

I keep getting the following error in Firebug:

> k.data( [Break On This Error]
>   false)a.mobile.activePage=k;h(k);y&&D&...dd(k).removeClass("
>   out in reverse "+

It's as if jquery mobile is performing some operation on the result? I don't want this to happen. Do I *have* to return a valid jquery mobile HTML page from my PHP?

Any insight greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Solution: use `<input type="button" id="login_submit" data-theme="a" value="Submit" />`

Now I can capture click events via:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#login_submit").click(function() {
    alert('clicked');
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Did you see my solution above?

Comment: You should use jQuery Mobile the way it was designed, and it was with 'progressive enhancement' in mind. The whole idea is about creating a page that would work even without javascript. Therefore I'd answer - you should return full page content after a login form is submitted. That's how the internet always worked anyway...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

using `data-ajax="false"` in form.

then you can disable jquery mobile auto ajax call